# loop a variable delimited by comma and enter each item to each row of the table SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, loops

lets say I have the variable x, which is equal to: x='3,4,5,6,7'

Then i have a table @tmpTable with two columns (respID and Responses)

On my @tmpTable the respIDs for each row are null.

I want the ids of each row there to be the values on my x variable above. (for example, row 1's respID=1, row 2's respID=2.. and so on..)

[image]
how to do this in SQL?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server (tsql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve as below using SSMS:

```
declare @S varchar(20)
set @S = '1,2,3,4,5'
declare @tempTable as table (col1 varchar(max), col2 varchar(max))

While len(@s) > 0
begin
    insert into @tempTable(col1) select left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)
    set @S=stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end

select * from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
SELECT 
  Responses.value('(/x/@ID)[1]', 'int') AS [ID],
  Responses
FROM YourTable
```

Sorry the image you had in your post has now disappeared so I don't remember the table name or the exact xml.  Have a search on google for "tsql  xml  xpath".

Comment: I just want to get the IDs from the variable x. which has a value of '3,4,5,6,7'. I dont want to get the values from the xml since its more complicated